# AmazonAppSyncClient() constructor not implemented exception in xamarin

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, graphql, aws-appsync

I want to use AWS AppSync in xamarin ,

this is the code I used (using graphQL) as described here :

https://gist.github.com/NeilBostrom/cab8b9275e39bb90ecf8e06ab980664b

but I got AmazonAppSyncClient() constructor not implemented exception

```
    public GraphQLService()
    {
            credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("Identity-pool-ID", // Identity pool ID
                             RegionEndpoint.USWest2 // Region
                             );
            graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient("https://6vl6q5h2c5bxrbmlimiia5hldy.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
                 new GraphQLClientOptions
                 {
                     HttpMessageHandler = new AWS4SignerMessageHandler(
                                               new AmazonAppSyncClient(),
                                               "AKIAIPYMG6M3MLZELEKA",
                                               "tW4NrTvfT5bX8DGI2GusiNWHtWB+9s918uq9QMWp")
                 });

    }
```

any solution please ?

thank you .

Comment: Is that a secret key? If so, you may want to redact it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258066/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the AmazonAppSyncClient isn't supported. With this said, given that its GraphQL you can use any HTTP client to access an AppSync API. It looks like you can fix this by changing your implementation of AWS4SignerMessageHandler & AmazonHttpRequestSigning such that it does not depend on an AmazonServiceClient. Looking at your gist, the only reason that it looks like you use it is for [the endpoint & region here](https://gist.github.com/NeilBostrom/cab8b9275e39bb90ecf8e06ab980664b#file-aws4signermessagehandler-cs-L81-L82) and the [config here](https://gist.github.com/NeilBostrom/cab8b9275e39bb90ecf8e06ab980664b#file-aws4signermessagehandler-cs-L63) which I think you could build yourself a google search led me to these [api docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TClientConfig.html).